# Reading properties file in install4j

Tags: java, installation, install4j, properties-file

I want to read properties file using install4j and set installer variable using it but the installer variable and the key in the properties file are different. So, how can I read in this way by using an action?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please add more details to your question

Comment: Yeap, you should show the part of the code where that installer variable is used and may be the relevant part of the file contents as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a "Read a properties file" action followed by a "Run script" action that copies the installer variable values like this:

```
context.setVariable("newName", context.getVariable("oldName"));
```